Overloading indexing operator assignment
I want to overload assigning a value to an overloaded index in a C++ class. Here is my code so far:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    void operator=(vector<string> val) {
        a = val[0];
        b = val[1];
        c = val[2];
    }
    string operator[](int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            return a;
        }
        else if (index == 1) {
            return b;
        }
        else {
            return c;
        }
    }

private:
    string a = "";
    string b = "";
    string c = "";
};

int main()
{
    // What I can do
    Test values;
    values = { "X","Y","Z" };
    cout << values[0] << endl;
    cout << values[2] << endl;
    //What I want to do:
    // values[1] = "XYZ";
}

I want to be able to assign, not just get the value of the index.
How could I do this? Ex.
values[1] = "XYZ"


string operator[](int index) should be string& operator[](int index). Note the reference qualifier &.

look at how it works in std::vector

A piece of advise: consider switch-case in operator[]

@AlexanderS And even better, define an enum class that only has 3 enumerators (to be used as indexes). The underlying type should preferably be std::size_t.

std::string default-constructs to an empty string. Writing explicity in-class initializers like string a = ""; adds clutter. Note that your operator= should return a Test& type and so you would return *this;. You should do a size test before assuming there are 3 values, or use .at().

Other dupes: Is it possible to assign a user-defined Array by index with operator overloading? - C++

The bracket operator[] function is user-defined. What it does is up to the programmer. In practice, however, it is most often used to implement some sort of a subscripting operation.
For subscripting, you want two (overloaded) versions of operator[]. Both return references.

non-const – The non-const version returns a reference to a data member of a non-const object.
const – The const version returns a reference to a data member of a const object.

// Subscripting Operators
// Version 1. returns a (non-const) reference.
std::string& operator[](int const index) {
    switch (index)
    {
    case 0: return a;
    case 1: return b;
    case 2: return c;
    default: throw std::runtime_error("Invalid subscript");
    }
}

// Version 2. returns a const reference.
// It operates on const objects, so the keyword `const` 
// must be used after the parameter list.
std::string const& operator[](int const index) const {
    switch (index)
    {
    case 0: return a;
    case 1: return b;
    case 2: return c;
    default: throw std::runtime_error("Invalid subscript");
    }
}

The compiler automatically selects the non-const version when working with non-const objects. Thus, it can appear on either side of an assignment operator. When it returns a reference to one of the data members of a class, that member can be modifed by an assignment.
// `values` is a non-const object of type `Test`.
Test values;

// Compiler selects the non-const version of `operator[]`.
values[0] = "Any way ";
values[1] = "the ";
values[2] = "wind blows.";

The compiler selects the const version of operator[] when it is used on a const object. Those can only appear on the right side of an assignment operator.
It is important to have the const version of operator[] in order to provide support for constant objects. This comes up frequently with functions that have parameters that are const. See, for instance, operator<< below.
// main.cpp
#include <iomanip>    // quoted
#include <iostream>   // cout
#include <vector>     // vector
#include <stdexcept>  // runtime_error
#include <string>     // string

class Test {
    std::string a = "";
    std::string b = "";
    std::string c = "";

public:
    void operator=(const std::vector<std::string>& val) {
        if (val.size() >= 3) {
            a = val[0];
            b = val[1];
            c = val[2];
        }
    }

    // Subscripting Operators
    // Version 1. returns a (non-const) reference.
    std::string& operator[](int const index) {
        switch (index)
        {
        case 0: return a;
        case 1: return b;
        case 2: return c;
        default: throw std::runtime_error("Invalid subscript");
        }
    }

#if 1
    // Version 2. returns a const reference.
    // It operates on const objects, so the keyword `const` 
    // must be used after the parameter list.
    //
    // As an experiment, you can change `#if 1` (above) to `#if 0`.
    // That will remove Version 2 from the build, and trigger a
    // compile-time error when `operator[]` is referenced in 
    // function `operator<<`.
    std::string const& operator[](int const index) const {
        switch (index)
        {
        case 0: return a;
        case 1: return b;
        case 2: return c;
        default: throw std::runtime_error("Invalid subscript");
        }
    }
#endif

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, Test const& t)
    {
        // Parameter `t` is a reference to a constant object. 
        // If you remove version 2. of the subscripting operator, 
        // this function will not be able to invoke `operator[]`.
        for (int const i : { 0, 1, 2 })
            ost << std::quoted(t[i]) << '\n';
        return ost;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test values;
    values = { "X","Y","Z" };

    std::cout << values[0] << '\n'; // Output: X
    std::cout << values[2] << '\n'; // Output: Z

    values[0] = "Any way ";
    values[1] = "the ";
    values[2] = "wind blows.";

    std::cout << "\nAll Values:\n\n" << values;
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp

When I removed version 2. of operator[], I received the following error message:

error C2678: binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Test' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Side note: For the most part, professional programmers do not use using namespace std; in their production work. That is why I deleted it here. It's okay to add std:: to the names you use from the Standard Library. (Otherwise, you can provide using declarations for the names you need. Just don't use the using directive using namespace std;.)

Return a reference in order to permit assignment.
Remember to overload both const and mutable versions. Make life easy on yourself and write a method to do all the work that the [] operators simply invoke:
#include <iostream>

struct point
{
    int x, y, z;
    const int & operator [] ( int n ) const { return index( n ); }
    int       & operator [] ( int n )       { return const_cast <int &> (index( n )); }

private:
    const int & index( int n ) const
    {
        switch (n)
        {
            case 0: return x;
            case 1: return y;
            case 2: return z;
        }
        throw "fooey";
    }
};

std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & outs, const point & p )
{
//  p[1] = -5;  // const object cannot be modified!
    return outs << "(" << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << ")";
}

int main()
{
    point p { 1, 2, 3 };
    
    p[1] = 7;  // mutable object can be modified
    
    std::cout << p << "\n";
}

